# How to add custom image to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to add a custom image to `tabViewController`. It's working fine for me; this is code I'm using:

```
[[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"]];
[[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc.png"]];
[[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse.png"]];
[[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore.png"]];
[[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"More-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"]];
```

The image doesn't fit into the tabbar (I'm unable to post the image).
Is there some design issue? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The width of your image should be (320/number of tab bar items). It means 320/4.

Comment: It doesn't have width problem, Its having height problem.

Comment: refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812972/add-custom-image-to-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: Can you make sure that your image height also as same as your tabbar? Are you using your own(Custom) tabbarcontroller?

Comment: Hope tabbar height is 44px, I give less then that only (I try with 40px & 38px height). It having some space at bottom, please refer above Url, you can see the output image

Answer (score 0):

Refer this one 
[Add custom image to UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812972/add-custom-image-to-uitabbarcontroller).

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
```

[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"]];

tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);

Answer (score 0):

```
 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

  [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected.png"]];
```

And also you need to make sure the size of your image fits the space.