# Add custom image to UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to add custom image to tabview controller, its working fine for me this is code I'm using

```
[[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"]];
    [[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyTc.png"]];
    [[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Browse.png"]];
    [[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Instore.png"]];
    [[AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"More-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"More.png"]];
```

the image not fit into the tabbar

out put

[image]

there is some design issue is there how can I fix this

Image goes over the tabbar, and some other background image is showing in selected tab (check 2nd tab).

How can I fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to lower the images in the TabBar could change the imageInsets:

try something like that:

```
  UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [AppDelegate.Tabctrl.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

  [tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home-Select.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home.png"]];

  tabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
```